# Programatically opening the "Open File" dialog in VLC

Tags: lua, vlc, playlist

I've written a VLC extension in Lua that will start each time VLC starts.

When the extension is activated (on load) I would like the first action to be opening the VLC `Open File...` dialog, and then continue once the user selects a playlist.  The main [VLC Lua docs](https://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/share/lua/README.txt) give details for creating new dialogs, but not for opening existing ones.

Also, if possible, I'd like to limit the filetype that the user is able to select from to being just my new playlist fileformat (*.myp)

Comment: There's no out-of-the-box way to do this. As of 2.2 you'd need to [create a file browsing dialog yourself](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=122028&hilit=dialog).